# NLTK Not working in MAC OSX

Tags: scikit-learn, nltk

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
k=[]
example=['Mary had a little lamb' ,  'Jack went up the hill' , 'Jill followed suit' ,'i woke up suddenly','it was a really bad dream...']
for i in example:
    k.append(word_tokenize(i))
```

I was trying to compile this code but its not compiling and is giving errors which goes as follows :

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
    from nltk.chunk import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/chunk/__init__.py", line 157, in <module>
    from nltk.chunk.api import ChunkParserI
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/chunk/api.py", line 13, in <module>
    from nltk.parse import ParserI
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/parse/__init__.py", line 79, in <module>
    from nltk.parse.transitionparser import TransitionParser
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/parse/transitionparser.py", line 21, in <module>
    from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file
  File "/Users/sudhir/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/Users/sudhir/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "/Users/sudhir/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
  File "numpy.pxd", line 155, in init sklearn.utils.murmurhash (sklearn/utils/murmurhash.c:5029)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

Comment: You've *probably* installed the wrong version of `numpy`, or some such. How did you get your components? Double-check your installation, or download Anaconda python that comes with `numpy`, `scikit` and the `nltk` bundled in. It's a large download but everything works together OOTB.

Comment: + for the Anaconda suggestion. I really find Anaconda useful to manage my Python stack. Also installing numpy and scipy through pip is a painful process. Anaconda comes with everything together.

Comment: `pip install -U numpy` , then `pip install -U nltk`. Or you can try `conda install nltk` or `conda update nltk`.